# Fetching a remote branch from a bare repo on usb key

Tags: git, git-branch

I've init a bare repo on a usb key (drive d:) and pushed some branches: `develop`, `feature-xxx-ui` etc. But, somehow I've also managed to push a `remotes/origin/feature-YYY` branch to the key. (see **USB Key** below)

How can I fetch commit `a20d561` branch `remotes/origin/feature-YYY` from the key. It seems not to be listed as a branch:

Here is my **local repo**:

```
c:\projects\my-super-app>git branch -av
  develop                       00eb70d [behind 5] Now loading config
* feature-xxx-ui                e2a7e75 Can now run commands
  master                        4d7a284 Merge branch 'release-0.7'
  remotes/origin/HEAD           -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop        e2a7e75 Can now run commands
  remotes/origin/feature-xxx-ui e2a7e75 Can now run commands
  remotes/origin/master         4d7a284 Merge branch 'release-0.7'

c:\projects\my-super-app>git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: d:\git\my-super-app.git
  Push  URL: d:\git\my-super-app.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop        tracked
    feature-xxx-ui tracked
    master         tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop        merges with remote develop
    feature-xxx-ui merges with remote feature-xxx-ui
    master         merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop        pushes to develop        (local out of date)
    feature-xxx-ui pushes to feature-xxx-ui (up to date)
    master         pushes to master         (up to date)
```

Here is my **USB key**:

```
c:\projects\my-super-app>d:

d:\git\my-super-app.git>git branch -av
  develop                    e2a7e75 Can now run commands
  feature-xxx-ui             e2a7e75 Can now run commands
* master                     4d7a284 Merge branch 'release-0.7'
  remotes/origin/feature-YYY a20d561 WIP-YYY xxxxxxx  <<<===== HOW DO I PULL/FETCH THIS?

d:\git\my-super-app.git>dir
 Volume in drive D is XXXXXX
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of d:\git\my-super-app.git

04/12/2014  10:30    <DIR>          .
04/12/2014  10:30    <DIR>          ..
04/12/2014  10:30    <DIR>          refs
04/12/2014  10:30    <DIR>          branches
04/12/2014  10:30                73 description
04/12/2014  10:30    <DIR>          hooks
04/12/2014  10:30    <DIR>          info
04/12/2014  10:30    <DIR>          objects
04/12/2014  10:30                23 HEAD
04/12/2014  10:30               112 config
16/12/2014  09:23            55 695 gitk.cache
               4 File(s)         55 903 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  31 424 446 464 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and create a branch on the usb bare repo, and see if you can fetch it from your local non-bare repo:

```
d:
cd d:\git\my-super-app.git
git branch wip a20d561 

c:
cd c:\projects\my-super-app
git fetch
# check if remotes/origin/wip exists
git checkout -b wip origin/wip
```

Comment: As simple as that! I was trying to play with `git branch -m` but it did not help me. Thanks.